# Multiple calls to Twitter streaming API in Node.js using ntwitter

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have the following code:

```
var access_token_key, access_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret, get_twitter, listen, twitter;

twitter = require('ntwitter');

consumer_key = 'bogus';
consumer_secret = 'fake';

// consumer
access_token_key = 'falsey';
access_token_secret = 'unreal';

get_twitter = function(key, secret) {
  return new twitter({
    consumer_key: consumer_key,
    consumer_secret: consumer_secret,
    access_token_key: key,
    access_token_secret: secret
  });
};

listen = function(feed) {
  var api = get_twitter(access_token_key, access_token_secret);
  return api.stream('statuses/filter', {track: feed.track}, function(stream) {
    console.log('setting up stream for %s', feed.track);        

    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('data for %s', feed.track);
      console.log('\t' + data.user.screen_name + ': ' + data.text);
    });

    stream.on('end', function(response) {
      console.log('ending stream for %s', feed.track);
    });

    stream.on('destroy', function(response) {
      console.log('destroying stream for %s', feed.track);
    });
  });
};

module.exports.listen = listen;
```

When I call `listen({track: 'superbowl'})` it works. Hurray! It does everything a little app should! I get this in the console:

```
setting up stream for superbowl
data for superbowl
    user: tweet
```

But after that, I call `listen({track: 'humble bundle'})`, it sets up the new stream, but this happens:

```
setting up stream for humble bundle
ending stream for superbowl
destroying stream for superbowl
data for humble bundle
     user: tweet
```

Am I doing something incorrectly here? Is there some concept of Node or of Twitter that I have not yet grasped fully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Twitter streaming API docs (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/concepts) under Access and Rate Limiting:

> Each account may create only one standing connection to the Streaming API. Subsequent connections from the same account may cause previously established connections to be disconnected. Excessive connection attempts, regardless of success, will result in an automatic ban of the client's IP address. Continually failing connections will result in your IP address being blacklisted from all Twitter access.

I.e., you can only have one streaming connection at a time. In order to receive both sets of results you need to instead use `listen({track: 'superbowl, humble bundle'})`. This means that you can't change what you are listening to and will have to stop listening, modify the query and restart listening instead.

Comment: Reading it again, yes. I was confusing the streaming API with site streams. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, by account does it mean developer account or the application itself? Because I have 6 applications in one account and they all fire up at the same time in one node.js app in order to capture different things. It's been working with no error for 5 months.

Comment: I've seen this answer a few times but no one seems to document HOW to disconnect the stream? I was using npm-twitter and there didn't seem to be a disconnect method.